# hide pills on jquery twitter bootstrap wizard

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

im using twitter bootstrap wizard http://vadimg.com/twitter-bootstrap-wizard-example/ , 
im trying to hide navbar so people cant see how much step they need to go.
is there any way to hide the navbar?
i try to do like that

```
.navbar{
  display: none
}
```

the result make navbar gone, but i cant switch step to another step and i dont know why.
theres no error on console when i try to inspect that.
is there any jquery function needed to hide the navbar? please help

Comment: Why not only hide the following nav items instead of the whole navbar? Or show them but disable selection like here: http://vadimg.com/twitter-bootstrap-wizard-example/examples/basic-disabletabclick.html?

Answer (score 0):

Try to hide it another way:

```
.navbar {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```